# Stirling Number Generating Function Relationship

Tags: functional-analysis, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

In "Generatingfunctionology" by Herbert Wilf, there is a section where he derives explicit formulas for Stirling numbers. (Please see images below).

I'm wondering how he arrives at the relationship in eq. 1.6.8 (I do not think I understand what how the derivative w.r.t 'y' is operating here).

Appreciate any input - thanks! [Equations / Relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku3rW.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is a use of a standard identity that appears throughout the book: $ky^k = y(ky^{k-1})=y\frac d{dy}(y^k).$ So, $$\sum_k k\begin{Bmatrix}n-1\\k\end{Bmatrix} y^k = \sum_k \begin{Bmatrix}n-1\\k\end{Bmatrix} y\frac d{dy}(y^k) = y\frac d{dy}\sum_k \begin{Bmatrix}n-1\\k\end{Bmatrix} y^k = y\frac d{dy}A_{n-1}(y).$$

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
A_n(y)= y \sum_{k} { n-1 \brace k-1} y^{k-1} +y \sum_{k} { n-1 \brace k} \color{red}{ k y^{k-1}}  .
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dy} y^k = k y^{k-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
and interchange the order of the sum & derivative.